# Why can't I import pg.py?

Tags: python, sqlite, pygresql

```
>>> import pg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    import pg
  File "C:\EPD\lib\site-packages\pg.py", line 21, in <module>
    from _pg import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I downloaded PyGreSQL 4.0 for Windows, and installed it into the `\LIB\site-packages` of my python directory.  When I try to import `pg.py`, I get this error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's unable to find libpq.dll. Make sure that the directory which contains libpq.dll from your PostgreSQL installation is in your Windows path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the C:\EPD\lib\site-packages\ directory? Perhaps you did not install to the right site-packages directory?